# Cannot rebase, stash or commit git repo on host filesystem from Vagrant machine: Unable to create /.git/index.lock

Tags: git, vagrant

Tried rebasing to production branch off a clean branch I haven't made any changes to that is a little behind.

Was told I have uncommitted changes and to either commit them or stash them, but `git status` reveals no changes were made to any files on this branch.

So just for the hell of it, decided to stash changes. When I try that, I get error:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/var/www/MyProject/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
Cannot save the current index state
```

So I tried this trick:

```
sudo rm -f /var/www/MyProject/.git/index.lock
```

But that didn't help. So I tried again, following that command with `git reset` but reset throws the same permission denied error.

So then I tried `sudo git reset` which worked, but then when I tested `git rebase production` I get this error:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
fatal: Unable to create '/var/www/MyProject/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
could not detach HEAD
```

How do I fix these permission issues?

This is a vagrant box running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: With which user id did you clone the repo? With which are you trying to use it? Maybe the output of `id` and `ls -lA /var/www/MyProject` will give you some hints.

Comment: @PaulHicks `id` gives me `uid=1000(vagrant) gid=1000(vagrant) groups=1000(vagrant),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),110(sambashare),999(admin)` and `ls` gives me `drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data vagrant  442 Oct 27 11:47 .git/` but not sure how to read these. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using different users to create and manage your repository.  Your repo was created by www-data and you're logged in as vagrant.

Your options are:

1. Log in as www-data (`su www-data`) before doing git work.
2. Change the owner of the repo to vagrant (`chown -R vagrant *`)
3. Change the permissions on the repo to allow group write since both ids are in the vagrant group (`chgrp -R vagrant *`)
4. Mount the disc or directory using the correct owners and permissions. For Vagrant, your Vagrantfile's `config.vm.synced_folder` configuration covers this: see the [Vagrant Docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html).

Whatever you do, make sure anything else that needs to use git retains whatever access it needs.  Since www-data created the repo, it's likely that you used some sort of web service / application to do it; therefore, if you change the owner of the repo to vagrant, you probably need to change the web service / application so that it is run by vagrant, too.

Comment: Tried both `chgrp -R vagrant *` and `chown -R vagrant *` but neither fixed the issue. Can't do `su www-data` because I don't have the password and have never logged in as that user.

Comment: www-data probably doesn't have a password.  You can set its password to be nothing using `sudo password -d www-data`. However you might be better off just cloning the repo again, using the correct user.

Comment: I actually pulled the repo in using SourceTree. It's actually located on my Mac but Vagrant symlinks it during `vagrant up`. This all started when I had to refactor the entire project into a new directory using PHPStorm.

Comment: Ah.  Then have Vagrant mount the source directory as vagrant instead of www-data. Your Vagrantfile can do that.  See [the docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html), in particular the "owner" and "group" settings.

Comment: Huzzah!! That fixed it! Could you update your answer so I can accept?

Comment: Point four should cover it.  I'll enhance it a little.